# Why send Hawkeye back in time to such an emotion-filled location?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-endgame

I just saw *Avengers: Endgame* for the third time, and noticed something confusing. Clint Barton / Hawkeye (Jeremy Renner) is sent back in time by himself, to test the time machine. He appears in a barn on his family farm. It stirs up overwhelming emotions for him. He hears his daughter's voice inside the house, sprints up onto the porch screaming for her, and then vanishes back into present time.

Why on earth would the team send Clint to such an emotionally-charged place? Why not just send him to some run-of-the-mill location, like a city, and have him grab something that had the date on it, like a newspaper?

Comment: Seems to have been *his choice* rather than the team's.

Answer (score 11):

#### The team was just supportive

There are no official sources for this and we don't see a scene on-screen where they do this, but I imagine they had a discussion of where Barton should go and Bartons' request being to go back to his house, to see his family again.

We should remember that Barton lost his family for 5 years now, it's natural that Barton would want to see them again, and the team being supportive as they are, accepting it.

Comment: This.  One last chance to see a loved one is something that few people would pass up.  Barton would choose that time and place specifically because it is such an emotionally charged place for him and he is not a heartless, soulless automaton.

Comment: It's been a while since I've seen the movie, but if I remember correctly, Hawkeye was a little hostile towards Black Widow for giving him potential false hope. Perhaps Hawkeye wanted to be sure he could see them again before fully committing to the mission

Comment: It's also worth noting that by sending Barton back to his farm, he'll be in a location that he knows very well. In addition, if he goes there and his family is hanging around then it's a good confirmation that he was actually sent to the past and not just another location in the present.

Comment: Another reason might be that Barton was quite a different person after the events of the snap. The rest of the team could have sent him to that time to try and inspire him to be a more traditional "good guy" again